# Grey grid showing up on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

So, I implemented google maps to our website but for some reasons since yesterday a grid appeared on the map when I browse the website with chrome but not with firefox.

And If someone else browse the website with chrome the grid isn't displayed.

I'm having a hard time finding out why I see this grid

Here is a picture of the map
[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting Chrome? It looks like it still thinks the images are loading.

Comment: Also, could you please post applicable code?

Comment: @jsve I just restarted chrome and it's even worse, the line are bigger. I will add the code

Comment: [Bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362889) - [issue in Google Maps Javascript API issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362889), see this [issue in Google Maps Javascript API issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594)

Answer (score 2):

It surely is a bug in webkit browsers not only Chrome.
I managed to fix this by adding this css:

```
.gm-style div {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.002);
}
```