# Google maps tile margin rounding issue in chrome

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome

I'm trying to display a google map on a page but it seems that for some reason the map is showing a gap between the first tiles both vertically and horizontally.

I'm applying an absolute position to the map container and have both the `width` and `height` as percentages, I also have the `right` and `bottom` set to 0.

It renders like the following:
[image]

Here is a live demo: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/EFvGr

I have also tried putting the map in a parent container and applying the same properties to that element but I get the same effect.

I've only been able to reproduce this in the latest version of Chrome.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: Perhaps [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594)?

Comment: Yup, that was it, all I needed to do was change `'version':'3'` to `'version':'3.14'`. Would you like to provide it as an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grey grid showing up on google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123677/grey-grid-showing-up-on-google-maps)