# Unwanted Horizontal & Vertical lines appearing on embedded Google Map API 3 - Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, wordpress

I'm using the [WP Google Maps Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/) plugin on my Wordpress site to display various maps (API 3):

http://www.escalamadrid.com/roca-real/

In chrome for OS X, I'm getting a 1px horizontal white line when displaying the map:
 [image: white lines]

This only seems to affect Google Chrome. I've tested in Safari and Firefox and the problem does not occur. I've attempted disabling some chrome extensions but to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grey grid showing up on google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123677/grey-grid-showing-up-on-google-maps)

Comment: I hadn't seen that post - but it does seem to be the same issue. A member of the Chrome team said it should be fixed in Chrome 35 due for release in mid-may. Guess I'll have to hold tight till then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue no longer occurs in Chrome Version 37.0